# How to hide scheduled Selenium/ChromeDriver Tests in Windows

Tags: selenium-webdriver, scheduled-tasks, selenium-chromedriver

We have automated web tests which use the chromedriver.exe and which have proved difficult to automate and schedule. The only way were able to run them on a scheduled task was to run as the group "Administrators". Any other user (even admins) and the task simply did not run.

Anyhow, the problem now is that the task windows pop up constantly when we are on the server. Checking the "hidden" box has not helped, they still pop up.

How can we run these tasks silently in the background?

[image]

Notes:

1. We are running chromedriver in "headless" mode i.e. no Chrome GUI.
2. We have tried the `HideCommandPromptWindow` option to no avail